# Enable hardware virtualization in windows 7

Tags: 64-bit, bios, virtualization, intel-pentium, hardware-virtualization

I'd like to enable the `Hardware Virtualization` functionnality in my Computer, so download the [Securable Tool](https://www.grc.com/securable.htm).

When i launched the program i got this result 
[image: demo]

**My computer's configurations :**
[image: dem2]

I ask:

- How can i enable the `Hardware Virtualization` ?
- What is the best way to do that?

Thanks,

Comment: We need your mobo make and model

Comment: @kinokijuf can you explain more plz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Your CPU does not support VT-x.](http://ark.intel.com/products/37212/intel-pentium-processor-e5200-2m-cache-2_50-ghz-800-mhz-fsb)